# Do I use enough tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

I made a question which I think is really helpful but I'm not sure if I tagged it detailed enough or didn't add enough tags.

- Do more tags help questions?
- Do tags matter that much?
- Is one tag enough for my question [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/66391/is-there-a-way-to-add-2d-lines-to-my-view-that-help-you-align)?

Comment: Complaining about downvotes is seldom constructive. If I had to guess, I'd say the downvotes here are because this is a question that should (could) have been asked on the [per-site Meta](http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @AʟE. I agree with that statement I was actually considering that but the core of the question is about tags and not about the question so that made my prefered choice SE's meta.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Do more tags help questions? Do tags matter that much?

Relevant tags do. Especially on large sites, like SO, it is impossible to go over every question posted. Tags are used by experienced users to see which questions they can answer. So using the right tags will address the right audience for your question. Irrelevant 'meta' tags will not help anyone.

It will also help Google and other search engines to correctly file your question. This will help you to get an answer, but also others to find your question back (tags have more weight in Google than your question body, so they are important).

> Is one tag enough for my question here?

That question can only be answered by users that have experience on your site. The site's own meta is the place to ask that question. I would suggest to try to find keywords from your question and see if there are tags for that. Maybe there is a tag for the product you use, the thing you are trying to do, etc.